# Swift 2- "Type 'String' has no member "PopulateArray"

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have the following class which populates all the "Breakfast" entries from a JSON file. Note that in my JSON file, "ingredients" is an array and "instructions" could be an array of arrays.

In the "Populate" function below, Swift is reporting 2 errors saying, "Type 'String' has no member "PopulateArray". "Type 'AnyObject' has no member "PopulateArray".

How do I fix this?

Here's the Swift Source.

```
import Foundation

class Breakfast
{
    var id:String = ""
    var name:String = ""
    var image:String = ""
    var servings:String = ""
    var ingredients:[String] = []
    var instructions:[AnyObject] = []

    func Populate(dictionary:NSDictionary) {

        id = dictionary["id"] as! String
        name = dictionary["name"] as! String
        image = dictionary["image"] as! String
        servings = dictionary["servings"] as! String
        ingredients = String.PopulateArray(dictionary["ingredients"] as! [NSArray])
        instructions = AnyObject.PopulateArray(dictionary["instructions"] as! [NSArray])
    }

    class func PopulateArray(array:NSArray) -> [Breakfast]
    {
        var result:[Breakfast] = []
        for item in array
        {
            let newItem = Breakfast()
            newItem.Populate(item as! NSDictionary)
            result.append(newItem)
        }
        return result
    }

}
```

The JSON Source can be found here: [JSON Source](http://pastebin.com/ecb2kuHp)

Comment: You may discover your answer by thinking about these questions: *What do you expect `String.PopulateArray` to do? Why?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `String` nor `AnyObject` seem to declare a method `PopulateArray` (unless it's in class extension you haven't included)

If your JSON has contains an array of strings for the "ingredients" key, then it will be an `NSArray` of `NSString`, which can be trivially converted to `[String]`:

```
ingredients = dictionary["ingredients"] as! [String]
```

Likewise, if your JSON always contains an array of AnyObject (`[AnyObject]`) you can populate it with:

```
instructions = dictionary["instructions"] as! [AnyObject]
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically when working with JSON, you'll want to use NSJSONSerialization to convert top level JSON data into their corresponding Swift types, here's a quick example of getting data, running it through a serializer and then accessing the JSON data by casting it into known Swift data types:

```
if let someJsonData = someOptionalData {

    if let jsonTopLevelDictionary = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(someJsonData, readingOptions: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject] {

         if let stringsArr = jsonTopLevelDictionary!["keyWithArrayOfStrings"] as? [String] {
           for string in stringsArr {

           // do stuff
           }

         }

    }

}
```

There are a few different ways to skin this cat, you can even check out something like SwiftyJSON which helps parse JSON data into their native swift types.